# Location based Criteria

Tags: location, maps, criteria

For number/date fields one can specify search/filter criteria with operators such as Greater Than, Less Than, Equal To, Between, etc.. For string fields, one can specify Starts With, Ends With, Contains, etc..

Similarly for LOCATION fields, using Maps (Graphically selecting location(s) plus additional text inputs), one can think of criteria such as Within this location hierarchy, Within radius of, etc. (and their NOT counterparts). Has similar thing been done before which I can refer? Is there a technical term for this, that helps my search? Will Google Maps API be of any help (looking for jump start before exploration)? This could be useful, for example, in real estate (buy/sell/rent) website.